# Does the Kernel slide over each time dimension individually in Conv1D convolutions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am dying to understand one question that I can not find any answer to:

When doing Conv1D on a multivariate time-series - is the KERNEL convolved across ALL dimensions or for each dimension individually? IS the size of the kernel [kernel_size x 1] or [kernel_size x num_dims]?

The thing is that I input a 800 by 10 time series into a Conv1D(filter =16,kernel_size=6)
And I get 800 by 16 as output, whereas I would expect to get 800 by 16 by 10 , because each time series dimension is convolved with the filter individually.

What is the case?

---

Edit: Toy example for discussion:

We have a 3 input channels, 800 time steps long. We have a kernel of 6 time steps width meaning the effective kernel dimensions are [3,1,6].

Each time step, 6 timesteps in each channel are convolved with the kernel. Then all the kernels elements are summed.

If this is correct - what is 1D about this convolution, if the image of the convolution operation is clearly 2-dimensional with [3 x 6] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convolve an "image" with multiple channels you sum across all the channels and then stack up filters you use to get a new "image" with (# of filters) channels. The thing that's a bit difficult for some people to understand is that the filter itself is actually (kernel_size x 1 x Number of channels). In other words your filters have depth.

So given that you're inputting this as a 800 x 1 "image" with 10 channels, you will end up with an 800 x 1 x 16 image, since you stack 16 filters. Of course the 1s aren't really important for conv1d and can be ignored, so tl;dr 800 x 6 -> 800 x 16 in this case.

---

Response to part 2:

*We have a 3 input channels, 800 time steps long. We have a kernel of 6 time steps width meaning the effective kernel dimensions are [3,1,6].*

This is essentially correct.

*Each time step, 6 timesteps in each channel are convolved with the kernel. Then all the kernels elements are summed.*

Yes, this is essentially correct. We end up with a slightly smaller image as we'll repeat this operation each time we slide the kernel over this timestep, giving us a 700 and something by 1 by 1 new image. We the repeat this operation # of filters times, and stack these on top of each other. This is still in the third dimension, so we end up with 7xx by 1 by (# of filters).

*If this is correct - what is 1D about this convolution, if the image of the convolution operation is clearly 2-dimensional with [3 x 6] ?*

For something to require Conv2d, it needs to have a 2nd dimension value greater than 1. For example, a color photograph might be 224 x 224 and have 3 color channels so it'd be 224 x 224 by 3.

Notably when we perform Conv2D, we also are sliding our kernel in an additional direction, for example, up and down. This is not required when you simply add more channels, since they're just added to the sum for that cell. Since we're only sliding on one axis in your example (time), we only need Conv1D.

Comment: Blazing fast stacker! This is the crucial info I needed - that my filter has DEPTH even though the keras documentation doesn't say JACK about that. Cool!

Comment: I have updated my question with  a toy example. Your answer provides the missing piece of information but I do not understand how reducing more than one dimension to one integer value is can be called 1D convolution. Other than that I basically upvoting this!

Comment: @ledawg I've updated my answer, hope you find that helpful. Also, please remember to upvote and mark correct answers to your questions as correct as this motivates people to help you out.

Comment: Regarding 7xx: only if the convolution with the kernel yields NaN as long the current time step is lower than the size of the kernel (so it doesn't happen for 1d kernels)?

Comment: You could always pad the ends of the time series with the mean value or something to maintain size, but when performing a convolution you're always going to shrink your image in the non-channels-dimensions because of the way the kernel is slid and how it can't go off the edge.

Comment: Fascinating - my code does not agree with you. My conv1d layer yields 800xfiltercount as an output tensor. Continue in chat?

Comment: I actually don't know how to force continuing in chat

Comment: You'd need to visit chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: The padding parameter is the key.